# how to convert "PWSTR" to "System::String^" in c++

Tags: c++-cli

I would like to know how to convert "PWSTR" to "System::String^"

```
   My code snippet follows here...

   array<System::String^>^ nsRecords;

   try
   {
     nsRecordCount = dns.query(ipAddressString);
     nsRecords = gcnew array<System::String^>(nsRecordCount);

     for(int nsRecord = 0; nsRecord < nsRecordCount; nsRecord++)
     {
   DNS_PTR_DATA record  = dns.getNth(nsRecord);
 // below line of code causing error C2440: '=' :  
     //cannot convert from 'PWSTR' to 'System::String ^'
       nsRecords[nsRecord] = record.pNameHost; 
     }

   }
```

I appreciate your help!

Thanks,
  Ramani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcnew String()` should be enough. BTW this is a C++/CLI question, not c++ 11.